# Where to Find these code in facebook developers page

Tags: javascript, facebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHYfW.png)I am trying to integrate fb from my page but it is saying that I haven't included it in app domain

```
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0&appId=337294694551004&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce=""></script>
```

**This is the code I want to get nonce??
Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you put a bit more information in. The full error message perhaps

Comment: The error you are talking about doesn’t sound as if it had anything to do with the nonce. You need to specify your domain in your app settings.

Comment: I have like mentioned the domain in the app settings as the error mentioned

Comment: can someone tell me where do i get the nonce